# lookup helm value based on range

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am creating a helm chart that has a multiple containers.

My values file look like this:

```
# environment variables
rabbitmqhost : "rabbitmq"
db-host : "mongo"
db-username : "root"
db-password : "root"


deployments: 
  - name: "service1"
    image: "Some-repo"
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    tag: "latest"
    env: 
      rabbitmqhost 


  - name: "api"
    image: "Some-repo"
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    tag: "latest"
    env: 
      rabbitmqhost 
      db-host 
      db-username 
      db-password
```

and my deployment.yaml looks like this:

```
{{ range $.Values.deployments}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .name }}

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .name }}
  template:
     spec:
        containers:
        - name: {{.name}}
          image: "{{ .image }}:{{ .tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env: {{ range $key, $val := .env}}
            - name: "{{ $key }}"
              value: "{{ $.Values.$key }}"
            {{- end}}

{{- end}}
```

I have found that this does not work, i as `value: "{{ $.Values.$key }}"` does not evaluate.
Is there a way to evaluate the $key dynamically?
Or do I need to build this in a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$map.key` syntax only works if the `key` is a known fixed string, but you can use the standard template `index` function with a variable string

```yaml
value: "{{ index $.Values $key }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by extending the logic to use "if has"

In my values file, i defined the environemnt variables like this:

```
# environment variables
env:
  rabbitmqhost : "rabbitmq"
  db-host : "mongo"
  db-username : "root"
  db-password : "root"

deployments: 
  - name: "service1"
    image: "Some-repo"
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    tag: "latest"
    env: 
      - rabbitmqhost 


  - name: "api"
    image: "Some-repo"
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    tag: "latest"
    env: 
      - rabbitmqhost 
      - db-host 
      - db-username 
      - db-password
```

And in the deployment template I changed it like this:

```
{{ range $deployment := $.Values.deployments}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ $deployment.name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ $deployment.name }}

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ $deployment.name }}
  template:
     spec:
        containers:
        - name: {{$deployment.name}}
          image: "{{ $deployment.image }}:{{ $deployment.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env: {{ range $key, $val := $.Values.env}}
            {{ if has $key  $deployment.env }}
            - name: "{{ $key }}"
              value: "{{ $val }}"
            {{- end}}

          {{- end}}

{{- end}}
```